# Jasmine Unit Test Fail - Argument 'DogController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn how to unit test Angular controllers using Jasmine.  I'm following this example [Unit testing AngularJS with Visual Studio, ReSharper and TeamCity](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/09/unit-testing-angularjs-with-visual-studio-resharper-and-teamcity/) which does everything in Visual Studio (VS 2015 in my case).  Below is all of my code.

```js
/* app.js */
;
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("demoApp", [
        "ng",
        "controllers",
        "services"
    ]);
}());

/* services.module.js */
;
(function () {
    var services = angular.module("services", []);
}());

/* controllers.module.js */
;
(function() {
    var controllers = angular.module("controllers", []);
}());

/* dog.service.js */
;
(function () {
    var dog = function() {
        var dogs = [
            { type : "Labrador", name : "Rover" },
            { type : "Tibetan Terrier", name : "Joey" },
            { type : "Yorkshire Terrier", name : "Rufus" }
        ];

        return {
            query : function() {
                return dogs;
            },
            add : function(newDog) {
                dogs.push(newDog);
            }
        };
    };

    angular.module("services").factory("Dog", [dog]);
}());

/* dog.controller.js */
;
(function() {
    var dogController = function ($scope, Dog) {
        $scope.pageTitle = "Dogs";
        $scope.dogs = Dog.query();
    };

    angular.module("controllers").controller("DogController", ["$scope", "Dog", dogController]);
});
```

Here is my controller unit test.  I created the test following the example.  I also created a test for my service following the example and that is working fine.  For some reason my controller unit test is failing.

```js
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>

///<reference path="~/app/app.js"/>
///<reference path="~/app/controllers.module.js"/>
///<reference path="~/app/dog.controller.js"/>

describe("Controllers", function() {
    beforeEach(module("controllers"));

    describe("Dog controller", function() {
        var scope, dog, controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            dog = {
                query : function() {
                    return [{ name : "TEST", type : "TEST"}];
                }
            };

            controller = $controller("DogController", { $scope: scope, Dog: dog });
        }));

        it("should set the page title as 'Dogs'", function() {
            expect(scope.pageTitle).toBe("Dogs");
        });

        it("should have 1 dog", function() {
            expect(scope.dogs.length).toBe(1);
        });
    });
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be given.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you execute the test? Have you included dog.controller.js in the list of files to load?

Comment: I'm using Resharper inside of Visual Studio to run the test.  According to the example I'm following I include files using the reference lines at the top of the spec.js file.  It is definitely referencing dog.controller.js.  I followed the same pattern for my service test and it worked great.